# Group totals in a sql pivot table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, radgrid, pivot-table

I am trying to create group totals in this pivot table

```
            create table test5(city nvarchar(10), race nvarchar(30), sex nvarchar(10), age int)
            insert into test5 values ('Austin',  'African-American', 'male', 21)
            insert into test5 values ('Austin',  'Asian', 'female', 22)
            insert into test5 values ('Austin',  'Caucasian', 'male', 23)
            insert into test5 values ('Austin',  'Hispanic', 'female', 24)
            insert into test5 values ('Austin',  'African-American', 'Unknown', 25)
            insert into test5 values ('Austin',  'Asian', 'male', 26)
            insert into test5 values ('Austin',  'Caucasian', 'female', 27)
            insert into test5 values ('Austin',  'Hispanic', 'Unknown', 28)
            insert into test5 values ('Austin',  'Asian', 'male', 29)
            insert into test5 values ('Austin',  'Caucasian', 'female', 31)
            insert into test5 values ('Dallas',  'Hispanic', 'Unknown', 32)
            insert into test5 values ('Dallas',  'African-American', 'male', 33)
            insert into test5 values ('Dallas',  'Asian', 'female', 34)
            insert into test5 values ('Dallas',  'Caucasian', 'Unknown', 35)
            insert into test5 values ('Dallas',  'Hispanic', 'male', 500)
            insert into test5 values ('Dallas',  'African-American', 'female', 36)
            insert into test5 values ('Dallas',  'Asian', 'Unknown', 37)
            insert into test5 values ('Dallas',  'Caucasian', 'male', 38)
            insert into test5 values ('Dallas',  'Hispanic', 'female', 39)
            insert into test5 values ('Dallas',  'African-American', 'Unknown', 41)
            insert into test5 values ('Houston',  'Asian', 'male', 42)
            insert into test5 values ('Houston',  'Caucasian', 'female', 43)
            insert into test5 values ('Houston',  'Hispanic', 'Unknown', 44)
            insert into test5 values ('Houston',  'African-American', 'male', 45)
            insert into test5 values ('Houston',  'Asian', 'female', 46)
            insert into test5 values ('Houston',  'Caucasian', 'Unknown', 47)
            insert into test5 values ('Houston',  'Hispanic', 'male', 48)
            insert into test5 values ('Houston',  'African-American', 'female', 49)
            insert into test5 values ('Houston',  'Asian', 'Unknown', 51)
            insert into test5 values ('Houston',  'Caucasian', 'male', 52);


    WITH T AS (
        SELECT 
               A.city, A.sex, 
               CASE
                    WHEN A.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-30_' + race
                    WHEN A.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40_' + race
                    WHEN A.age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50_' + race
               END AS age_range_race
        FROM test5 AS A
    )
    SELECT  *
    FROM T
    PIVOT( COUNT(age_range_race) FOR age_range_race
           IN(
              [20-30_African-American], 
              [20-30_Asian], 
              [20-30_Caucasian], 
              [20-30_Hispanic],
              [31-40_African-American], 
              [31-40_Asian], 
              [31-40_Caucasian], 
              [31-40_Hispanic],
              [41-50_African-American], 
              [41-50_Asian], 
              [41-50_Caucasian], 
              [41-50_Hispanic]
              )
    ) AS P
    ORDER BY city, sex
```

I need them to be formatted like this with the group totals on top.

[image: 1]

I am going to be putting the pivot in a radgrid, so if there is a way to do it in the grid or with C# that would be good as well. Any suggestions will help as I am looking for basically any way to make this happen. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using query similar to this:

```
select city, sex,
count(case when race = 'African-American' and age between 20 and 30 then 1 else null end) as [20_30_African-American],
count(case when race = 'Asian' and age between 20 and 30 then 1 else null end) as [20_30_Asian],
count(case when race = 'Caucasian' and age between 20 and 30 then 1 else null end) as [20_30_Caucasian],
count(case when race = 'Hispanic' and age between 20 and 30 then 1 else null end) as [20_30_Hispanic]
-- add all other columns here
from test5
group by city, sex WITH ROLLUP
order by city, sex
```

Comment: I am not following, should the select statement be in the "WITH T AS" select or the one below it?

Comment: Can you please provide a working example as I don't fully understand. Thanks

Comment: did you try above query? run this query and you'll understand what to do next. Add columns for all other groups 31_40, 41_50, i gave you a working sample with first four columns.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. This is perfect, except the first row is duplicated. is there a way to get rid of it?  Thanks http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c1e8/3

Comment: You can do this - `SELECT  *
   FROM T where NULLIF(city,'') IS NOT NULL`

Comment: This worked until I added a third column, I get this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0300a/5   the third row is now duplicated, is there any way to get around this? Thanks

Comment: you need to rethink what you want to do, if you want to show type then it will show them as different rows because they are different values. There is no way you can avoid it, unless you are trying to do something else that i dont understand.

Comment: I am trying to get this result, http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/7241/crossus.png  where there is a total grouped by the first column. Thanks

Comment: check this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0300a/47, you can identify row and skip it, try this and skip type you don't want using where `type <> 'value to skip'`

Comment: This works great until age is in the column section instead of the crosstab section. When it is in the crosstab section it still needs to be a case statement. I tried different variations of this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0300a/61 and it did not work. This is the what the ufn_GetAge function look like,  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0300a/62.  Is there any way to have a case statement in a GROUPING Function? Thanks